# Keyboard shortcut for navigating to code usage example in PyCharm 2016

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pycharm

When I left-click `ArgumentParser()` in the code below and press <kbd>F12</kbd>, it takes me to the specific file/line where `class ArgumentParser:` is defined:

```
def init():
    arg_parser = ArgumentParser()
    args = arg_parser.parse_and_sanitize_args()
```

Just kidding!  It used to do that, but I reinstalled PyCharm, and now it doesn't. Now pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> just selects the root-level folder in the Project menu.

Which setting controls this behavior?  Would I need to turn on one of the many keyboard shortcut "themes" to make this work?  The <kbd>F12</kbd> behavior is standard in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by navigating to `Settings -> Keymap` and selecting the `Visual Studio` keymap scheme.